# Shadow price of constraints in JuMP (Julia)

Tags: julia, linear-programming, coin-or-cbc

I have the following LOP.

```
using JuMP, Cbc
productionProb = Model(solver = CbcSolver())

@variable(productionProb, x >= 0)
@variable(productionProb, y >= 0)

@objective(productionProb, Max, 7.8x + 7.1y)

@constraint(productionProb, assemblyCondition, (1/4)x + (1/3)y <= 90)
@constraint(productionProb, testingCondition, (1/8)x + (1/3)y <= 80)

solve(productionProb)
```

I am using the cbc solver and using julia to solve this problem. However, I would want to get the shadow price for the constraints. In particular, I would want to get the shadow prices for the constraints, assemblyCondition and testingCondition.

Anybody knows the code / function to do this? I have tried getdual() but it didnt work.

Comment: Shadow prices are dual variables in Linear Programming. For a MIP solver like CBC the term `dual` has a different meaning and actually refers to the LP relaxation of the problem.

Comment: remove `solver = CbcSolver()`, so default Solver is used and it should work

Answer (score 4):

JuMP doesnt support dual variables from MIP calls, and the Cbc solver is the MIP version of the Clp solver, so you just need to use

```
productionProb = JuMP.Model(solver = ClpSolver())
```

**how to get dual**

I had to dig up an old bilevel programing book to verify this vierd nomenclature

*In
economic terms, it is common to refer to the dual variables as shadow prices*

So what you are looking for are the dual variables of the primal problem (shadow price of the variables) and the dual variables of the dual problem (shadow price of the conditions, usually called the reduced cost)

```
a = @variable(productionProb, x >= 0)
b = @variable(productionProb, y >= 0)

getdual(a)
getdual(b)

getdual(assemblyCondition)
getdual(testinCondition)
```

Comment: Hi, I have mentioned in my question that I have tried getdual() to obtain the dual variables but it did not work. It returned be NaN. @isebarn